# Unable to create a "list" in NetLogo

Tags: list, netlogo

I am trying to create simple "list" but it returns error.

when I type:

observer> `set a [2 4 6]`

it returns: `ERROR: Nothing named A has been defined`

I have NetLogo version is 5.1.0 and operation system Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
Is it some bug or I am doing it not right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error doesn't have anything to do with lists. `a` needs to be declared as a global in your code tab for that to work. So add:

`globals [ a ]`

to your code tab.